# Get an entry of certain length using LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select addressline1, city
from person.address
where city LIKE '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] '
```

I want to get cities with 5 characters by operator `LIKE`. Is it possible?
And my result is empty.

[image: Please check this image]

Comment: You should use `LEN` funtion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql

Comment: why there is a blank in your like?

Comment: Note that trailing blanks matter when it comes to LIKE.

Comment: okay but on exam we force to use that Operator Like, that the problem

Comment: What happens if you remove the space at the end of your `LIKE` condition?

Comment: Yes!, that was mistake by space! thanks now its works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
SELECT addressline1, city FROM person.address WHERE LEN(city) = 5;
```

However, if you are hell bent on using `LIKE`, use this.

```
SELECT addressline1, city FROM person.address WHERE city LIKE '_____';
```

The `LIKE` solution above, however is practical only for small lengths, as your case.

Comment: Yes its work aswell, that better idea i think less wrote.thanks!